# host webapp in my machine trough virtual machine

Tags: iis, hosting, vmware

im using *windows 7 ultimate* in a *vmware non-commercial version*,  i have an mvc4 asp.net app running within *IIS*. i manage to get my app working on *localhost (vmware win 7)* perfectly.

now im asking 2 questions :

1 - is it possible to browse my app from a machine connected to my local network ?

2 - is it possible to host my app trough this configuration and to make it available in internet. like http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my public ip adress)

thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both questions, if your browser machine can hit the port the server machine is serving the app on. On WAN, you would need to make sure your router didn't block requests to the server's port, and the same for any modem/firewall that connects you to the internet at large. Also, if your public ip is not static, it may change.

Comment: i think i should clarify something, my vmware windows is running inside an ubuntu. the *network adapter* setting of my vm *network connection* is set to *bridged & replicate physical network connection state* wich gives my vm *192.168.0.106* ip adress, wich is fine.
trough my ubuntu browser, when i cant navigate to *http://192.168.0.106*

Comment: Do you have Windows Firewall on? Is there some other firewall blocking (I assume) port 80 in your vm network connection? Does your web application host know that the IP address 192.168.0.106 is a request for the application? You may need to add 192.168.0.106 as a host header.

Comment: yeah i think it has something to do with windows firewall. how can i verify this in winwos 7 ??

Comment: It is available under Control Panel -> System and Security. You can [turn it off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/turn-windows-firewall-on-or-off) for testing and then setup a windows firewall rule allowing IIS port to be accessed.

Comment: here is the solution i found :

- network connection set to bridged & replicate physical network connection state.

- go to windows firewall *advanced settings*, then under *inboud rules*, click *new rule ...* then check *predifined*, scroll to bottom of the list and selected *world wide web services HTTP*, *next*, make sur *world wide web services HTTP* is checked. *next*, *finish*